# Function not being passed as prop to child component in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass a method from a parent component to a child. The method, however, never appears in the props of the child component. I do not understand what is wrong with this, this is the absolute basic thing to do in React, and it just won't work. Of course, it works fine in about hundred other places in the app codebase. The method in question is `getVerificationStatus`. It gets invoked in child as a follow up on a promise returned by calling `verifyStripeProviderAccount`. The child component also has 5 other props passed in by HOCs, and they all work, it's just this one parent prop that is simply not injected for some reason.

The function is undefined, all other props from redux, stripe, etc are present, and the error I am getting is : "TypeError: this.getVerificationStatus is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:8837:16"

The code is below, but I have removed some irrelevant parts for brevity.
Parent:

```
import {getUserVerificationStatus} from "../services/UserService";

class VerifyAccount extends Component {

    state = {
        verificationStatus: VerificationStatus.UNVERIFIED
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getVerificationStatus();
    };

    getVerificationStatus = () => {
        if (this.props.user.paymentProcessorId) {
            getUserVerificationStatus()
                .then(response => this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    verificationStatus: response.status || this.state.verificationStatus
                }));
        }
    };

    render() {
        return <Card>
                {this.state.verificationStatus === VerificationStatus.UNVERIFIED && (
                    <VerificationSteps getVerificationStatus={this.getVerificationStatus}/>
                )}
                {this.state.verificationStatus === VerificationStatus.PENDING && (
                    ...
                )}
            </Card>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return ...
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return ...
};

const StripeVerifyAccount = compose(
    withAuthentication,
    withUserType(UserType.PROVIDER),
    injectStripe,
    withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true}),
    injectIntl,
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(VerifyAccount);

export default () => {
    return <>
        <Elements>
            <StripeVerifyAccount/>
        </Elements>
    </>;
}
```

the child:

```
import {verifyStripeProviderAccount} from "../services/UserService";

class VerificationSteps extends Component {

    state = {...}

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        verifyStripeProviderAccount(body)
            .then(errors => {
                if (errors) {
                    this.props.emitError("verification_documents_error", 5000);
                } else {
                    this.props.getVerificationStatus();
                    this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        loading: false,
                        success: true
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    loading: false
                });
                this.props.emitError("verification_error")
            });
    };

    render() {
        return <some stuff, not important>
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return ...
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return ...
};

export default compose(
    withAuthentication,
    withUserType(UserType.PROVIDER),
    injectStripe,
    injectIntl,
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(VerificationSteps);
```

Comment: "it's just this one parent prop that is simply not injected for some reason. " Why do you think this method isn't passed as a prop? Are you getting an error? What other evidence do you have to support this claim?

Comment: More importantly what happens when you run your code? What do you expect to happen differently?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice what do you mean? I simply expect that function to be invoked so it can do its work. The error I get is much like what you get any other time you invoke an undefined function - "TypeError: this.props.getVerificationStatus is not a function". Also, during runtime when this.props is inspected, it has pretty much all the props it should besides this single function.

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. I suggest that you edit your question to include the exact error message.

Comment: Interestingly, you are not getting "getVerificationStatus is undefined". So this prop is passed as something. I suggest using the debugger to see the value of `this.props.getVerificationStatus`. Then you need to figure out why it is set to what it actually is instead of the function you think you are passing. I would check your `mapStateToProps()` and `mapDispatchToProps()` functions. Do they have anything with the same name `getVerificationStatus`.

Comment: One potential source of the problem is that you are passing some props through redux and some directly with the JSX tag of the component. In my experience, this leads to bugs like what you see here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I thought as much, so I added mergeProps to connect to see how all the props are merged together. Interestingly, it only got state and dispatch props, but no parent props, so redux is simply not getting that function. I would suspect the problem could be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the call to `verifyStripeProviderAccount()` is not within a method of your child class, thus `this` is not properly initialized at that moment. I would even expect you to have a syntax error actually.

Try with:

```
import {verifyStripeProviderAccount} from "../services/UserService";

class VerificationSteps extends Component {

state = {...}

async componentDidMount(){
    verifyStripeProviderAccount(body)
            .then(errors => {
                if (errors) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    this.props.getVerificationStatus();
                    this.setState({
                        ...
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.props.emitError("verification_error")
            });
}

render() {
        return <some stuff, not important>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return ...
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return ...
};

export default compose(
    withAuthentication,
    withUserType(UserType.PROVIDER),
    injectStripe,
    injectIntl,
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(VerificationSteps);
```

Comment: I apologize, I was trying to tidy up the code as much as possible an removed the actual function within which it is called. I edited the code of child class, please take a look again. It actually is invoked within an arrow function, so this is properly initialized. All calls to this.setState or this.props work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In a parent component, I have

```
    setPerson = (person) => {
    this.setState({
        person: person
    })
}
```

I pass it to a Form Component like so

```
     <EditLinkForm
         person_id={this.state.person.id}
         link_id={this.state.link_id}
         link_name={this.state.link_name}
         link_url={this.state.link_url}
         setPerson={this.setPerson}
      />
```

Then this is how the Form (the Child Component) uses it

```
       axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/admin/edit_link/',
        postData,
        AuthenticationService.getAxiosConfig()
        )
           .then(response => {
                this.props.setPerson(response.data.person)
            }
        )
```

The full source is [here](https://github.com/xtien/schwartze-frontend/blob/master/src/Person.js)

Comment: That's very nice, but I am dong the same thing:
1. define an arrow function in parent
2. pass that function as a prop to a child
3. invoke in child's body

and still, it doesn't work, even though it should. It works in essentially any other place in my codebase but this one.